# nginx keeps redirecting to some weird default port other than 80, 443. using wordpress here

Tags: wordpress, nginx, certbot

I have followed the steps of configuring SSL certificate with nginx. However, after configuration it automatically keeps redirecting to port number 8899, which is neither related to http or https port.

Of course, before using `certbot` commands to setup the SSL certificates and letting `certbot` automatically update my nginx `.conf`files, I was using port number 8899 to server my **wordpress** website. And at the time, it did work purely in http.

After `certbot` setup, I have change my nginx configuration files to work only on port 80, 443. However, even though I have double checked that there is no metion of port 8899 in any of my nginx conf files, the running nginx keeps redirecting to port 8899 whenever I attempt to access through port 80 or 443.

I have tried restarting the nginx service, and rebooting the machine. These atttempts failed to remove this weird symptom.

I would appreciate if anyone could nudge me any hints on solving this problem.

Below are my nginx configuration files.

### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.net

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /home/ubuntu/data/wordpress/wordpress;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name mysite.net;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;


        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

---

UPDATE

I have found out that for some reason, when I try to access with 443 , then it will respond with a 301 redirect to port 8899.

However, there is no redirection commands in any of my nginx configuration file except from 80->443.

Here is my latest `mysite.net` nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ;


    # SSL configuration
    #
    #listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    server_name mysite.net;
    root /home/ubuntu/data/wordpress/wordpress;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;



    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.


        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;




        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    #listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    #listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a browser's cache problem to me. Have you tried `curl http://localhost//`? If this still gives you a redirect, then you need to see your nginx's log.

Comment: @sipp11 I have updated the question. It looks like a redirection from 443->8899 is occuring somewhere. And this redirection does appear in the /var/log/nginx/access.log . But I really did not define any redirections from 443->8899 anywhere. The only configuration files that are in motions are:
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf  , /etc/nginx/sites-enable/mysite.net   /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf

Comment: @sipp11 an all of these three files have no commands that mention 8899... Any guesses where I might be missing?

Comment: Is there anything in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`? If nothing, then I think you have to update your wordpress URL to :80 too.. That should be the reason.

Comment: @sipp11 my god. you were right. The wordpress had "http://example.net:8899" set as its siteurl and home in `wp_options` table in the mysql db it was using. I changed both of them to `https://example.net` and it works now.. nginx configuration was not the problem after all. I did not know that wordpress would be the problem since it look so isolated from the nginx server stuff. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Cheers to @sipp11, who help me in the comments to solve this.

The solution was to simply change the `siteurl` and `home` url in the wordpress mysql db. Nginx configuration had nothing to do with this issue.

nginx was doing its job properly. redirect 80 -> 443, and from 443 serve the files from my wordpress directory.

But since wordpress had been thinking `http://example.com:8899` as the home url, I guess while processing the php files, it automatically triggered redirecting to port 8899.

That explains why the whole wordpress worked only when I connected port 8899 to an nginx server directive.

The reason why wordpress had `http://example.com:8899` set as its `siteurl` and `home` in the first place was because of my first attempt of setting up wordpress under port 8899 as a test. At that time I changed the default port from 80 to 8899(because apache2 was using up port 80 and nginx kept failing to bind to port 80).